# Moving individual labels & rule-based labelling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I have been playing around with labels and came to a problem. Hopefully someone can pinpoint whether I'm doing something wrong or there is a systemic hurdle in Qgis.

**Are you allowed to move labels manually in Qgis IF the chosen type of labelling is "rule-based"?**

When I change labelling type to Single labels, moving individual labels works like a dream. But under rule-based it just doesn't work, no matter what I do.

I'm using the Bonn version (Qgis 3.2.3), and have followed the BurdGis Youtube tutorial, as well as some other forum threads.

Comment: Could you expand on the "moving labels around"-part? Are you adjusting them manually? If so, how? Are you adjusting them based on field values?

Comment: I mean that I added x,y,rotation columns and linked them to the proper label location variables (in Labels/Placement/Data defined, for every rule-label - yellow colored), as per the YouTube tutorial by BurdGIS (link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0hFiiA31cg). And well, when using the Labels/Move Labels and Diagrams icon, I cannot move any individual label when rule-based labelling is applied.